# Passing multiple parameters in outbound gateway of Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

**I have the following Configuration :**

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="opgateway" request-channel="rallyUpdateRequest"
    url="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/9792864541?key={key}"
    http-method="POST" request-factory="rallyHttpRequestFactory"

    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    transfer-cookies="true"
    reply-channel="rallyUpdateResponse">
    <int-http:uri-variable
        name="key"
        expression="payload.secondArg" /> 
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

And the Gateway interface :

```
//@interface
public interface RallyUpdater {
    String updateDefect(@Payload String payload, @Header String key);
}
```

I have main Function:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "context.xml");
....
        RallyUpdater updater = ctx.getBean("rallyUpdateGateway", RallyUpdater.class);
        String res=updater.updateDefect(defect,key);

        System.out.println("Response  ::::::::::"+res);
```

This throws me an error:

*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine header name. Possible reasons: -debug is disabled or header name is not explicitly provided via @Header annotation.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.determineHeaderName(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:229)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.access$500(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:80)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper$DefaultMethodArgsMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:300)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper$DefaultMethodArgsMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:262)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.mapArgumentsToMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:163)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:80)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.toMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.doConvert(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:157)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:78)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:347)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:414)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:374)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.updateDefect(Unknown Source)
    at com.aa.qcrallysyncmgmt.base.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

*
**I need to pass the payload as post data and the key in the URL.

Why this throws error while we can give the payload.secondArg?
Any other configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't follow with the recommendation from the StackTrace?

```
updateDefect(@Payload String payload, @Header("key") String key);
```

From other side it isn't clear to me how you are going to do this `payload.secondArg`, since you payload is `String`.

For me the config should be like this:

```
<int-http:uri-variable name="key" expression="headers.key" />
```

Otherwise you should show the `<gateway>` configuration too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Artem.
When I put the <int-http:uri-variable name="key" expression="headers.key" /> it is throwing the same error. 
here is the gateway:

 <int:gateway
        id="rallyUpdateGateway"
        service-interface="rally.RallyUpdater"
        default-request-channel="rallyUpdateRequest"
        default-reply-channel="rallyUpdateResponse" />

Comment: thanks Artem, I did not notice the name of the parameter in the annotation, after addig that it worked

Comment: Artem, Will we be able to modify the URL dynamically? I want to pass the 9234264541 also dynamically. 
When i passed key in the following way  _ url="h ttp s://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/{key}"_
and passed the value of {key} with **"9234264541?key=kj2hkj3h2k43.."** 
 it threw error:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: According to your sample, it should be like this: ` url="rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect{key}?key={key}"`. From other side consider tou use `url-expression` to build the URL dynamically against `requestMessage` and with `beanFactory` access.

Comment: BTW, it's looks like separate question. So, be kind to accept this my answer.

Comment: Thanks Artem, Do you have a link which explains this with example?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-http/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/http/HttpProxyScenarioTests-context.xml